"p5.SerialPort is not a constructor" Need help connecting p5.js with Arduino
I am tyring to connect my arduino to P5.js through node js for a school assignment. We need to download the Serial Port application from github, install it in our terminal, connect our arduino, connect to p5js and I think also node js.
I have downloaded the serial port application as well as node js. I have followed instructions to get it running in my terminal. I have recieved the "p5.serialseriver is running!" message. However, in my p5.js sketch, when I try to run the code for the  next step, I  get an error that says "p5.SerialPort is not a constructor"
let serial;
let latestData = "waiting for data";

function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  serial = new p5.SerialPort();
  
  serial.list();
  serial.open('/dev/cu.usbserial-1120');
  serial.on('connected', serverConnected);
  serial.on('list', gotList);
  serial.on('data', gotData);
  serial.on('open', gotOpen);
  serial.on('colse', gotClose);
            
}

Hoping to connect the Arduino to P5.js

You have to add some code to index.html in order for editor to recognize Serial port:
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5.serialserver@0.0.28/lib/p5.serialport.js"></script>


There is also an app called p5.serialcontrol which will help format code for serial connections.
For example, the following code was generated for my system using the app p5.serialcontrol:
let serial;
let latestData = "waiting for data";

function setup() {
 createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

 serial = new p5.SerialPort();

 serial.list();
 serial.open('/dev/tty.usbmodem143301');

 serial.on('connected', serverConnected);

 serial.on('list', gotList);

 serial.on('data', gotData);

 serial.on('error', gotError);

 serial.on('open', gotOpen);

 serial.on('close', gotClose);
}

function serverConnected() {
 print("Connected to Server");
}

function gotList(thelist) {
 print("List of Serial Ports:");

 for (let i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {
  print(i + " " + thelist[i]);
 }
}

function gotOpen() {
 print("Serial Port is Open");
}

function gotClose(){
 print("Serial Port is Closed");
 latestData = "Serial Port is Closed";
}

function gotError(theerror) {
 print(theerror);
}

function gotData() {
 let currentString = serial.readLine();
  trim(currentString);
 if (!currentString) return;
 console.log(currentString);
 latestData = currentString;
}

function draw() {
 background(255,255,255);
 fill(0,0,0);
 text(latestData, 10, 10);
 // Polling method
 /*
 if (serial.available() > 0) {
  let data = serial.read();
  ellipse(50,50,data,data);
 }
 */
}

I was able to connect to an Arduino UNO and successfully ran this code:
unsigned long LoopTimer = 0;
byte outputValue = 0;

const int LoopTime50 = 50;
const int LoopTime100 = 100;
const int LoopTime20000 = 20000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (micros() >= LoopTimer) {
    LoopTimer += LoopTime100;
    outputValue += 8;
    Serial.println(outputValue);
  }
}


You will have to change the serial port name for your system.  You should be able to download the app here: https://github.com/p5-serial . Use this app to open the serial port also.

thank you! I ran the first code that you suggested and it went through. I thought something was missing. The module video from my school didn't show the functions at all. I am new and though somehow they were being defined some other way.
